# What is Hillbilly Boogie?

Tags: genre

I love blues rock and like some of related folk music. What is hillbilly boogie? Is it much different than normal boogie?

Comment: Where did you hear this term? Can you provide some context?

Comment: I think you will find [this audio segment](http://www.npr.org/2011/11/15/140112547/the-history-of-hillbilly-boogies-earliest-days) by Ed Ward (one of the great "rock historians") to be enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

HillyBilly Boogie is often called Country Boogie. So it is the same :)

Edit: 
Most of the Country-Musicians had one Country Boogie in its programs. Example for Country Boogie are Shot Gun Boogie von Tennessee Ernie Ford, the guitar Boogie von Arthur „Guitar Boogie“ Smith or the Hillbilly Boogie of the Delmore Brothers.
The wording HillBilly Boogie was used in the early 30s later was it called Country-Boogie

Comment: Any accounts of this? Details about why they are the same would be nice too.

Comment: As I understand 'hillbilly' has become generally considered a derogatory term (or always was, but there wasn't much concern for political correcteness), so it's natural that it would become replaced by a more neutral word.